# Need explanation on how these particular php classes work

Tags: php

I have hard time understanding a few pieces of code. Hope you can help me with these newbie questions.

```
class ChatBase{

    // This constructor is used by all the chat classes:

    public function __construct(array $options){

        foreach($options as $k=>$v){
            if(isset($this->$k)){
                $this->$k = $v;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ChatUser has nothing more than two empty protected variables and it extends the chatBase. Instatiation:

```
  $user = new ChatUser(array(
        'name'        => $name,
        'gravatar'    => $gravatar
    ));
```

My question is what the constructor part does? Why we are swapping these key/values?

Another question:

```
class DB {
    private static $instance;
    private $MySQLi;

    public static function init(array $dbOptions){
        if(self::$instance instanceof self){
            return false;
        }

        self::$instance = new self($dbOptions);
    }
```

Basically I have hard time understanding where this comes from new self($dbOptions); What is 'self; refering to in this case?

How I could console.log the value of self or any other variable when in class? Many thanks for clearing this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's comment the following code:

```
public function __construct(array $options){
```

Create the __constructor (which is a function automatically executed when creating a new instance of the class by using `new Class()`) and accept a parameter that has to be an array, and that we save to `$options`.

---

```
    foreach($options as $k=>$v){
```

Iterate through `$options` and set `$k` to the value of the key (eg. `name` or `gravatar`) and set `$v` to the value (`$name` or `$gravatar` in your initalizer)

---

```
        if(isset($this->$k)){
```

Check if the current class has a property by the name of `$k` (the key). Eg. "does this class have a property named `name`"?

---

```
            $this->$k = $v;
```

If the property exists, set it to the value (eg. `$name`):

Answer (score 1):

1)

The constructor allows you to set instance properties (from the "whitelist" of already defined ones) by submitting an associative array to the constructor when instantiating an object.

---

2)

There is no such thing as console.log in PHP, but you can use [echo](http://www.php.net/echo) or [var_dump](http://www.php.net/var_dump) instead. In that case, `self` refers to the class.

Answer (score 0):

In your first question, `$this->$k = $v;` is creating new properties on `$this`.

While looping, `$k` will be `'name'` and `$v` will be `$name`.  `$this->$k` is the same as doing `$this->name`, so it's setting `$this->name` to `$name`.

In the second question, `self` refers to the current class.  So, `new self($dbOptions)` is like doing `new DB($dbOptions)`.